# Auth_Time Is missing from JWK KeyCloak 18.0

Tags: keycloak

I installed Keycloak 18.0.0 and configured The database vendor to MySQL. also i created a realm and my client. When i  requested keycloak to authenticate using grant_type=password, the client-id, username, and password, it responses to me with the access token, but this access token doesn't contain the auth_time claims. any idea how I can include it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "auth_time" not includes in **access token** from Keycloak.

it include **id token**. It can be get by adding "openid" scope when you call get token.

This is example of call by curl

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1234' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid'
```

I decode it from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)
Get the "auth_time" claim.

```
{
  "exp": 1660748251,
  "iat": 1660730251,
  "auth_time": 0,
  "jti": "77a2000d-9876-4754-92df-10ca3c93fdbc",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test",
  "aud": "admin-cli",
  "sub": "7a5579a8-485a-435e-83b3-e0e2101ef20c",
  "typ": "ID",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "255a1543-ccb9-40bf-983f-93057df3f92b",
  "at_hash": "anFxw9f0KgIk5dGu5GInBA",
  "acr": "1",
  "sid": "255a1543-ccb9-40bf-983f-93057df3f92b",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "Tom Cruise",
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "given_name": "Tom",
  "family_name": "Cruise",
  "email": "user@test.com"
}
```

it is zero(0) value. I think it is same time "iat"(Issued At) claim.

I tested it with changing version , grant_type and scope. I found it depends on this combinations.
This is test result.
default scope means (profile email), openid means(openid profile email)

I don't know the reason but just "auth_time" is optional and it is changed by conditions.

| version | grant type | Scope | access token | ID token |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19.0.2 | password | default | No | No |
| 19.0.2 | password | openid | No | auth_time = 0 |
| 19.0.2 | code | openid | auth_time = iat | auth_time = iat |
| 18.0.2 | password | default | No | No |
| 18.0.2 | password | openid | No | auth_time = 0 |
| 18.0.2 | code | openid | auth_time = iat | auth_time = iat |

Comment: In older keycloak versions auth_time is coming in access token which obtained from password grant type.
Further, even in latest versions auth_time comes in access token generated via authorization_code grant. I'm still confused why auth_time is not available only in access tokens generated by password grant type in new keycloak versions.

Comment: @wannix, Thanks your pointing. it changed by Keycloak version, grant type and scope. I updated the test result in my answer. But I don't know why it changed by conditions.